# why it's returning NA with following R statement

Tags: r

I came across simple code as below, I am not sure why output is returning NA's. please help me understand this code.

code :

```
x=c(1,2,3,4)
k = x+2 [(!is.na(x)) & x>0]
```

output:

```
[1]  3 NA NA NA
```

Comment: As a simplification, see the output of `2[(!is.na(x)) & x>0]`. This is the same as `2[c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)]`. Since `2` is a vector of length 1, the additional slots are filled with NAs.

Comment: Whereas `(x+2)[(!is.na(x)) & x>0]` will return `[1] 3 4 5 6`

Comment: As a simplification, see the output of 2[(!is.na(x)) & x>0]. This is the same as 2[c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)]. Since 2 is a vector of length 1, the additional slots are filled with NAs.. it works

Answer (score 3):

The indexing is done on the expression "2", not on "x + 2".  You need

```
k = (x+2) [(!is.na(x)) & x>0]
```

to get what you expected.